# How to make this query more efficient in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

```
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8','Content-Type':'application/json'}
data = {
  "statements" : [
      {
        "statement" : "MATCH (n:Product) RETURN n.name, name.id",
        # "parameters" : { "nproduct" : 5 }
      } ]
}

r = requests.post(URL, headers = headers,json=data)
data = r.json()['results'][0]['data']
```

I want to extract nodes from neo4j database. If I have a large amount of Product nodes in the database, how can this query be possible to extract all nodes? The current query has to load all product nodes into memory.

Comment: The `name.id` in your Cypher code should cause an error. `name` is an unbound variable. Did you mean to use `n.id`?

Comment: @cybersam yes, n.id.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how large is large. The best way to limit this is to use [LIMIT](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/limit/) and return sets of Products at a time to your application

Comment: Luanne, could you give an example of code on how to get all nodes by your suggested method?

Comment: Your application will have to iterate and send the query with a LIMIT till no more rows are returned. Alternatively, use a bolt driver to consume results as you require (Neo4j 4.0 features reactive drivers).